# write to physical address using mmap object

Tags: python, mmap, pci

I want to write directly to the physical memory address of the host.
As far as I know, I need to allocate a virtual address on my processand then I can work with it.
In my Python code, I see that the memory value was changed, but in the physical memory address this change not happened.

```
mem_file = os.open("/dev/mem", os.O_SYNC)
bar0 = 0x92000000
mapped_memory = mmap.mmap(mem_file, rounded_to_pagesize , 
mmap.MAP_PRIVATE, mmap.PROT_READ | mmap.PROT_WRITE, 0, bar0)
mapped_memory.read(4)
output: '\x00\x1a\x00\x10'
mapped_memory.seek(0)
mapped_memory.write('0x1')
mapped_memory.seek(0)
mapped_memory.read(4)
output: '0x1\x10\x00\x05\
```

But when I check the value of the physical address, I see no change was done and even restart this section code will give me the old value address.

Answer (score 1):

Use `map.MAP_SHARED` instead of `map.MAP_PRIVATE`. From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/mmap.html):

> `MAP_PRIVATE` creates a private copy-on-write mapping, so changes to the contents of the mmap object will be private to this process, and `MAP_SHARED` creates a mapping that’s shared with all other processes mapping the same areas of the file.

Comment: I changed to MAP_SHARED and still the value of this physical address is not changed.

Comment: mem_file = os.open("/dev/mem", os.O_RDWR | os.O_SYNC)
self.mapped_mem = mmap.mmap(mem_file, rounded_to_pagesize,mmap.MAP_SHARED ,mmap.PROT_READ | map.PROT_WRITE,offset=bar0)
self.mapped_mem.write('7')